# Clang LeakSanitizer memory leak detection with optimized code

Tags: c, memory-leaks, clang, address-sanitizer, leak-sanitizer

### 1.Background

- Let's consider a C file `a.c` with following content as a memory leak [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void Foo() { malloc(1); }
int main() { Foo();  return 0;}
```

- On one hand, as expected, Clang [*LeakSanitizer*](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html) (which is integrated into Clang [*AddresSanitizer*](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html)) detects the memory leak if the following command is run:

```
$ clang++ -g -fsanitize=address a.c; ./a.out

=================================================================
==...==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 1 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x... in malloc (/.../a.out+0xa114e) (BuildId: ...)
    #1 0x... in Baz() (/.../a.c:2:14
    #2 0x... in main (/.../a.c:3:14
    #3 0x... in __libc_start_call_main csu/../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:16

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 1 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

- On the other hand, Clang *AddressSanitizer* documentation [Usage](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#usage) section mentions:

> To get a reasonable performance add `-O1` or higher.

### 2.Concern

- Clang *LeakSanitizer* **does not detect** the memory leak if the following command is run (the code generation option `-O1` has been added):

```
$ clang++ -O1 -g -fsanitize=address a.c; ./a.out
```

### 3.Question

Can memory leak still be detected by Clang *LeakSanitizer* when code optimization level 1 or higher is used?

- If the answer is **yes**, please provide a minimal reproducible example ([MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) proving it.
- If the answer is **no**, please explain **why** (link to Clang compiler source code, ...).

### 4.Remarks

- Clang *LeakSanitizer* documentation [Usage](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html) section does not explicitly mention that code optimization shall not be used.
- Above observations were made with version 18 of [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org), installed on Linux Ubuntu 22.04.3 using LLVM [automatic installation script](https://apt.llvm.org).
- As explained by user17732522 in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78170333/clang-leaksanitizer-memory-leak-detection-with-optimized-code?noredirect=1#comment137811500_78170333), the `a.c` file example in the Background section does not lead to memory leak detection when the `-O1` option is used because:

> *The optimized program won't have any actual memory leak. The malloc call will be optimized away since it doesn't affect observable behavior*

Comment: The optimized program won't have any actual memory leak. The malloc call will be optimized away since it doesn't affect observable behavior. The leak sanitizer was also never intended to not have false negatives as far as I remember.

Comment: Once optimized, ```malloc``` call will be optimized away because no where else it has been utilized. Please take a look at the ```dis-assembled``` instructions for both with and without ```-O1```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your minimal example is *too minimal* -- `clang` was able to optimize *everything* away from it:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000401120 <+0>:     xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000401122 <+2>:     ret
```

As you can see, none of `Foo` or `malloc` remain.

To make it a bit more realistic, try this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* Foo() { return malloc(1); }
void Bar(void *p) { printf("p = %p\n", p); }
int main() { Bar(Foo());  return 0;}
```

```
clang -g -O0 -fsanitize=address a1.c && ./a.out
p = 0x502000000010

=================================================================
==191==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 1 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x4c8822 in malloc (/tmp/a.out+0x4c8822) (BuildId: a27851507d14179bca1fa40aa114a3e5ffa99c23)
    #1 0x50644d in Foo /tmp/a1.c:4:22
    #2 0x506493 in main /tmp/a1.c:6:18
    #3 0x7f9a74195149 in __libc_start_call_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x28149) (BuildId: 7ea8d85df0e89b90c63ac7ed2b3578b2e7728756)
    #4 0x7f9a7419520a in __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2820a) (BuildId: 7ea8d85df0e89b90c63ac7ed2b3578b2e7728756)
    #5 0x42a324 in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x42a324) (BuildId: a27851507d14179bca1fa40aa114a3e5ffa99c23)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 1 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

And now with `-O1`:

```
clang -g -O1 -fsanitize=address a1.c && ./a.out
p = 0x502000000010

=================================================================
==197==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 1 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x4c8822 in malloc (/tmp/a.out+0x4c8822) (BuildId: 1ffaa6630367e5a8f0a95663181cd0d01efdc513)
    #1 0x50646a in Foo /tmp/a1.c:4:22
    #2 0x50646a in main /tmp/a1.c:6:18
    #3 0x7f804f1c020a in __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2820a) (BuildId: 7ea8d85df0e89b90c63ac7ed2b3578b2e7728756)
    #4 0x42a324 in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x42a324) (BuildId: 1ffaa6630367e5a8f0a95663181cd0d01efdc513)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 1 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```